# Copy a geometry from one feature to another without attributes?

Tags: qgis, geometry, copy

With QGIS it's easy to add a new part to an existing feature/geometry but I can't see how to copy/paste this part from another existing feature/geometry.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For copying just the geometry between existing features there is the plugin Geometry Paster: https://github.com/nextgis/geometry-paster

Answer (score 39):

Yes it is possible, see instructions below:

1. Start an edit session on both layers that you want to do the copy/paste between.
2. Use the Select feature by rectangle tool to select the feature in the map (copy from).
3. Click the Edit (menu)>Copy Features button.
4. Highlight the layer in the TOC that the feature will be pasted to.
5. Click the Edit (menu)>Paste Features button.

Comment: The only issue with this is that QGIS will take the attributes and dump them into the new table in the order it finds them, ignoring all column names, etc. I find this to be a bit annoying! It would be nice if there was an option to copy just the geometry, and I think perhaps that is what nippo is asking.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: This copy/paste does not seem to take attributes with it. The features I pasted say NULL for all fields in the attribute table. How can I make sure these attributes stay with the features when I paste them into a different layer?

Comment: @Dar Sounds like a good idea for a feature request.

Comment: i realize this is an older thread, but QGIS 2.2 allows for copy and paste of features AND attributes, but only transferring attributes when there is exact field name match, regardless of schema/field order. I do wish there was an Append or Field Mapping tool so you could also specify attribute carry-over where field names are different.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 2.14.5 and I'm having an issue where doing a copy & paste as new layer on selected features results in NULL attribute values.
Luckily, this "Save as... [ ] use only selected features" method presented here works a treat! http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197667/qgis-attributes-null-after-copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

Old discussion but another answer if your source geometry is in a layer well supported by the DB Manager (PostGIS, GeoPackage, etc.):

1. Get ID of feature to be copied (Identify Features tool)
2. Open SQL Window on that database in DB Manager.

```
SELECT <geom> FROM <layer> WHERE id = <#>
```

3. Load as layer

You have the geometry in the original projection without attributes in a scratch layer.