# QGIS Attributes null after copy paste

Tags: qgis

I have QGIS 2.14.

I opened a .shp file (with dbf etc) and selected a few features. Created a new QGIS project and pasted features as new Vector Layer.

The attributes table was created automatically in correct schema (field names & types) however the values are NULL.

I have explored other questions on stackexchange but they seem to be focusing on schema or field definition problem, in my case the schema is exactly same but still NULL values appearing.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way to load some selected features into a new project file is to save the selected features first into a new shapefile, then load the selected shapefile into the new QGIS project document.

To do that

- Select the targeted features from the original shapefile
- Right-click the layer from which you select the features -> Go to Save as
- Check the "Save only selected features" located under Encoding, as you can see in the image below

[image]