# QGIS 3.6 - Deleted Polygons

Tags: qgis, shapefile, table, mapping, plot

I'm putting together a large map consisting of some big datasets, and unfortunately deleted some (around 25) polygons from a key layer when editing a smaller version of the map for a different request. The data for these polygons is still in the attribute table. I need these polygons back and plotted on the map. I don't want to remove the layer and add it back again as I spent a few hours inputting extra data to the attribute table, and I would have to do this again.

Is there a way I can replot these deleted polygons and keep the data I added in the attribute table?

Comment: Maybe this question could help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297531/replace-existing-geometry-in-qgis-3

Answer (score 1):

Join can always `join vector layers` (e.g. wrongly edited & vanilla version) and then `delete duplicate geometries`. Maybe the attribute table will need some tweaking afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Another method:

1. Draw one of the deleted polygons. Don't enter any attribute data.
2. Open the attribute table. Select two features:

   - the no-geometry feature that has the attributes for the feature you just drew.
   - the no-attribute feature you just drew
3. Merge the two features using the `Merge selected features` button on the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar. In the dialogue window that pops up, select the attribute-only feature and click the "take attributes from selected feature" button.

   [image]
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for every deleted polygon.