# QGIS - Add or overwrite the geometry of an existing record using the GUI interface

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins

Is an existing tool, or plugin with editing tools, which would allow a user to edit geometries of existing records, but from already generated geometry on other layers.

Either

A) Insert a geometry (say, from the clipboard) onto an existing record.

Or

B) Update the geometry (lets say from the clipboard again) of an existing record.

So for an example, you have a record on layer A, it has a geometry. You do some geoprocessing and come up with a different geometry on Layer B and would like that to replace the geometry of a record in layer A.

A tool that would be something like

*Copy > Paste (Update geometry of selected record)*

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20942/copy-a-geometry-from-one-feature-to-another-without-attributes the answer describes a plugin that sounds like Esri *transfer geometry*.

Comment: Yep that plugin works. Geometry Paster.